# automatically find the object "this" refers to in js

Tags: javascript

Im quite new to javascript and sometimes I find it really hard to find what object a keyword 'this' refers to. Is there a code editor that is able to do that for me? Or any other advice that could help me :)
Thanks!

Comment: Paste some code you're having trouble with. That will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: I think your are looking for `alert(this.constructor.name);`

Answer (score 1):

There's a [great resource on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp).

In summary:

It (this) has different values depending on where it is used:

- In a method, **this** refers to the owner object.
- Alone, **this** refers to the global object.
- In a function, **this** refers to the global object.
- In a function, in strict mode, **this** is undefined.
- In an event, **this** refers to the element that received the event.
- Methods like call(), and apply() can refer **this** to any object.

Answered with regard to [getting function name here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179861/javascript-get-function-body) and with regard to [getting function body here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/how-to-get-the-function-name-from-within-that-function)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I know how it is used and what i'm looking for is an automatic way to reveal the corresponding object in a long and hard (obfuscated) code. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: It's evaluated at runtime, so looking at the code won't tell you anything. The code needs to be executed to understand what **this** means. Functions are mutable in javascript and can be defined (created) at runtime. You can have a function which creates functions through lambdas. To say ' I wan't to know what **this** means in a program ' is to say ' I want to know how the program is evaluated up to the point where this line of code is called.' The only way to know that is to evaluate the code.